# Deep Link with UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, nsdata, deep-linking

I have deeplinking set up in my app for opening a UIViewController based on a string included in the deep link URL. 
Is it possible to deep link into the app from another app and send a UIImage?

If so should I be sending it as a UIImage or converting to NSData or is there a better way such as shared user defaults?

Thank you

Comment: An image encoded into a URL would make for an impossibly long URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using some service like [branch.io](https://branch.io). You can add some additional parameters to your link (image URL or base64 string). See [documentation](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/configuring-links/guide/).